# Children's fantasy series with east asian siblings and black liquid in pots involved

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I only remember snippets from the book. If someone could help me find it that would be much appreciated.

I feel like the children were Japanese but I'm not sure about this. The main was an older sister, probably around 12, and the other main was her little brother.

I remember:

- definitely something about a car ride and the little brother picking his nose and eating it, getting called out by his sister; this is near the beginning of one of the books
- something about ending up at the bottom of a waterfall and being cared for by orcs or something
- the main is a swimmer and upset about puberty (boob development) because this will create drag
- something about black, oily liquid in a pot that worked as a portal. an illustration of this also appeared on a cover of one of the books

This was definitely published before 2010.